# converting subprocess out put to an integer

Tags: python-2.7

I am facing some challenges in python and I need some help.
I am trying to convert subproccess output into an integer. 
I have several directories in the form of year. For example running the command ls -l /directory, will return

2015
2016
2018

When I check the output type, it shows that the data is in the string format.
Which I should be able to convert into an integer.

However when I try the following code:

```
child = subprocess.Popen("ls -l /directory | awk '{print $9}'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 

output = child.communicate()[0]

for line in output.split("\n"):
 print int(line)
```

I receive the following error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"

Please help.